# Is it possible to have more than one complete directed graphs? And if yes, how many? I found a formula but I can't make sense of it

Tags: algorithm, graph, combinatorics, directed-graph

### 3<sup>C<sub>n</sub><sup>2</sup></sup>  = 3<sup>[num of arcs in undirected graph for some reason]</sup>

Is the formula I found relating to this, I would imagine it means for every node you can either have an arc pointing to it, from it, or both ways, hence the 3, then I have no Idea why they wouldn't use

#### n*(n-1)

being the num of arcs in a directed graph.

Comment: Only with a nonstandard definition of "complete". I can't seem to find a term for those graphs in a couple minutes of searching; I would say "weakly complete" by analogy with "weakly connected".

Comment: If you define "complete directed graph", it might be easier to answer your question. You can [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: yes, by more complete graphs that would include "weakly complete" so like only in one direction, and there's not much I can edit in since I barely know what it means either, that's why I was so confused when i found the formula too lol

Comment: to be clear, I was just learning about them and found a list of formulas that included this, so the formula found me, not the other way around

Comment: I got it guys, thanks a ton anyways